# Extract all ONLY IPs from the text, between tags

Tags: javascript, tags, ip, extract

Could you please help to do the following in JavaScript:

The text contains something like that:

```
text_to_parce = "<b>word</b>  <b>192.168.0.1</b> <b>name</b> <b>192.168.1.19</b> <b>address</b>"
```

From this string I want to extract ONLY IP addresses, other tagged info should be ignored, to the array to get the following:

192.168.0.1
192.168.1.19

```
var ip_pattern= /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/gi;

var userip_array = text_to_parce.match((/<li>(ip_pattern)<\/li>/)[1]).join("\n");

message.innerText = (userip_array);
```

It seems to be not working at all. Please help where is the mistake!

Comment: `(/<li>(ip_pattern)<\/li>/)[1]` What you were you hoping that would do?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside a regular expression. And there's no `<li>` in `text_to_parce`, so why are you trying to match that?

Comment: Are you trying to put `<li>` around the matches when you insert them into `innerHTML`?

Comment: Don't use `.innerText`, it's an IE-only property that doesn't exist in FireFox. You should use `.textContent` instead. But if you want HTML tags like `<li>` to be processed, you have to use `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for two ip as you show.

```js
text_to_parce = "<b>word</b>  <b>192.168.0.1</b> <b>name</b> <b>192.168.1.19</b> <b>address</b>";
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
var a=text_to_parce.match( numberPattern );
var ip_1=a[0]+'.'+a[1]+'.'+a[2]+'.'+a[3];
var ip_2=a[4]+'.'+a[5]+'.'+a[6]+'.'+a[7];
console.log(ip_1);
console.log(ip_2);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, but how to exclude the IP-like looking garbage, if the text contains also something like 567.645.465.656 (<-- But this garbage is not inside the tags...)